# In sqlAlchemy, relationship on AbstractConcreteClass doesn t consider single inheritance

Tags: sqlalchemy

given:

- class1 that is AbstractConcreteBase with 2 child
- class2 and class3 that are child of class1 with concrete = True in **mapper_args**, and class 2 is also polymorphic on "discriminator"
- class4 and class5 that are child of class2, with polymorphic_identity  = 'class4' or 'class5'
- relatedClass that is a class that have a ManyToOne relationship with class1, let's say in the attribute relatedAttrivute.

in a code sense i have the following (is more for the idea:

```
class Class1(AbstracConcreteBase, Base):
    
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('related_class.relatedAttr_id'), primary_key=True)
    
    @declared_attr
    def related_attribute(self):
          return relationship("RelatedClass")


class Class2(Class1):
    __tablename__ = 'class2'
    
    discriminator = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
         'polymorphic_on': discriminator,
         'concrete' = True,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'class2'
    }

class Class3(Class1):
    __tablename__ = 'class3'
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'class3'
    }

class Class4(Class2):

    __mapper_args__ = {

        'polymorphic_identity': 'class4'
    }

class Class5(Class2):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'class5'
    }

class RelatedClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'related_class'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    relatedAttr_id = Column(Integer)
    relatedAttr: Mapped['class1'] =  relationship('class1', back_populates='related_attribute')
    # Add other attributes as needed
```

if i do a query on relatedClass, for instance :

```
a = session.scalar(select(RelatedClass).where(RelatedClass.id ==1))
```

when i access the relationship doing:

```
a.relatedAttr
```

i get class2 or class3 but nevere class4 or class5, even if discriminator in class2 should yield class 4 or 5.

After checking the query that is done by sqlAlchemy, i guess that apparently the mapper that is taken into account is only the class1 mapper (that is polymorphic_on type) and not the child mapper.
So when i pass for instance 'polymorphic_identity': 'class5' on class5, he is checking for this identity in type of the pjoin, and not in pjoin.discriminator, like i would like .

so this case should implement an "and" in the query, it should check on pjoin.type ( for the polymorphic union in abstractConcreteClass)  and pjoin.discriminator (for the polymorphism on class2).

There is a way for doing this ?

i tried:

- move "concrete" = True in class4 and class5
- try to put a "polymorphic_on"= discriminator in the class1
- investigate on what sqlAlchemy do under the iron